# How to 'hide-users' in application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have an application with users/user-profiles. Presently, users can view others profiles, send messages, and favorite user profiles. I'd like to also add the feature to allow users to 'hide-user' profiles so that they won't see the user ever again in search, or anything. And provide the option in 'settings' to 'un-hide' the user as well.

How might I do this? I haven't a clue as to where to begin with this feature.

(If you need any code examples, models, controllers please ask and I will happily provide)

Kind regards,
Sonny

Answer (score 0):

I believe one approach would be to create a many_to_many relationship via the has_many :through association between users and hidden users. And likewise another many_to_many relationship between users and hiders (i.e. users who are hiding the user). In the end, you should be able to do something like this:

`some_user.hidden_users` and `some_user.hiders` (i.e. all the users that are hiding some user). You probably won't need the second one most of the time.

So the first thing to do would be to create a join table called hiders_hidden_users (or whatever you want) which would contain only two fields: `hider_id` and `hidden_user_id`.

Note, that in reality, those ids will both refer to a User record. Your HidersHiddenUser model will look something like this:

```
class HidersHiddenUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hidden_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "hidden_user_id"
  belongs_to :hider, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "hider_id"
end
```

Then, you need to set up the relationships in the User class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hiders_join, class_name: "HidersHiddenUser", foreign_key: "hider_id"
  has_many :hidden_users_join, class_name: "HidersHiddenUser", foreign_key: "hidden_user_id" 

  has_many :hiders, through: :hiders_join
  has_many :hidden_users, through: :hidden_users_join
end
```

Note, that you have to specify the class name and foreign key when writing the has_many relationship with the join table. Note, also that you have to specify the relationship twice with the same model.

Then, say some_user wants to hide user1 and user2. All you would need to do is something like this:

```
some_user.hidden_users << user1
some_user.hidden_users << user2
```

Although I have not tested this, I believe it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a couple of ways to do this, the first approach that comes to mind would be to establish a self-referencing many to many relationship.

You will need to create the join table (I shall call it `suppressed_users`). I will show the rails model, as the migration wouldn't have anything other than the foreign keys.

```
class SuppressedUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :suppressed_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key=>"suppressed_user_id"
end
```

And in the `User` model, in order to help DRY up your code, you can use a [`scope`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to easily filter all the users that this target user has decided to suppress (or hide):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :suppressed_users // Optional

    scope :without_hidden_users, -> (target_user) do
        where.not("exists (?)", 
            SuppressedUser.select("1")
              .where("users.id = suppressed_users.suppressed_user_id AND suppressed_users.user_id = ?", target_user))
    end
end
```

**Note about the scope:** What I'm doing here is creating a dependent (or correlated) subquery, in which I check whether the target user has suppressed (or hidden) the user we're looking at at the moment. In other words, the dependent subquery is executed for each row in the `users` result set (those not filtered by other `where` or `join` conditions and such). With proper indexing, this should not have an impact on performance.

**Note about `has_many :suppressed_users`:** This is technically not needed for the query I've shown, so if it is not relevant for anything in your system, you should be safe to remove it.

So, if I am presently logged in, and I want to search for a list of users meeting some condition, in your controller you would do something like this:

```
User.without_hidden_users(@current_user.id)...other conditions and such as needed
```

Assuming `@current_user` represents the currently logged in user.