# How to mark every favorited item?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a site where users can "save" images into albums. They are related as ManyToMany IE:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    album = models.ManyToManyField('Album', blank=True, null=True)

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I can easily display a list of all images a user has ever saved. But there is a separate page where users can discover new images.

How can I hide all existing saved images from that page? Is there a query to grab all recent images that are *not* on that user's saved images list?

Also, if I do pull them all, can I easily add a property to those so that they look different on the page? IE on Pinterest if you have favorited an image before, the Heart is colored in.

I found this post but I don't understand the code example given in Ruby: [How to 'hide-users' in application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584359/how-to-hide-users-in-application)

I know I could just create a big list of ID's and say something like:

```
if image.id in user_saved_list:
     #add CSS class
```

But that seems like the wrong way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
images_not_in_users_albums = Image.objects.exclude(album__user=user)
```

If you want to pull them all first and show which ones are in the albums, your method looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you, I am pretty new to databases and django so didn't know an exclude function or equivalent SQL query existed.